# quickly find a subfolder

Tags: vba, excel, subdirectory

So i have a piece of code that scans through the subfolders contained in a source folder. I know the first part of each subfolder name (or at least, this is a known variable i scroll through), the remaining part is an "issue number" that determines which design is most recent. Inside these subfolders are the files that i then copy into some other directory, for further use.

The trouble is i am using a For loop to scan through EVERY subfolder, until it finds the relevant start section of the folder name, and then recording the second half to compare.

This takes considerable time (there are something in the region of 21,000 subfolders and the list grows every day) and i was hoping to find a quicker way of achieving the same end.

Is there such a thing or do i just grit my teeth and bear it!?

If it helps, the format of the folders is always the same, eg DP0123456_00_01_003, currently i'm searching for the DP0123456 part and recording the rest as a comparator. Below is what i am using so far...

```
Sub Build_Issue_list()
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject, objFolder As Folder, objSub As Folder
    Dim MajArr(99) As String, MinArr(99) As String, DoArr(999) As String
    Dim FullArr(99) As String
    Dim IssCnt As Integer

    Dim StrSourceFolder As String

    Dim TopIssue As String
    Dim TmpStr As String
    Dim DpNo As String

    Dim dpCount As Integer, DpScroll As Integer

    Dim StartRow As Integer, StartCol As Integer

    Dim FoundIt As Boolean
    Dim I As Integer
    IssErr = False

    'default to start looking for list is "a5"
    StartRow = 5
    StartCol = 1
    dpCount = GetTableRows(StartRow, StartCol)
    'MsgBox DpCount

    For DpScroll = StartRow To dpCount
        DpNo = Cells(DpScroll, StartCol)

        'THIs BLOCK TAKES A DPNO AND FINDS THE HIGHEST ISSUE OF IT FOUND.
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject 'creates a new File System Object reference
        Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(StrSourceFolder) 'get the folder
        IssCnt = 0
        For Each objSub In objFolder.Subfolders 'for every sub-folder in the folder...
            'see if the DPno matches
            If objSub.Name Like DpNo & "*" Then
                'note that one instance is found
                FoundIt = True
                'record the rest as 3 seperate parts
                TmpStr = Replace(objSub.Name, DpNo & "_", "")
                MajArr(IssCnt) = Left(TmpStr, 2)
                MinArr(IssCnt) = Mid(TmpStr, 4, 2)
                DoArr(IssCnt) = Right(TmpStr, 3)
                'combine these for later
                FullArr(IssCnt) = MajArr(IssCnt) & MinArr(IssCnt) & DoArr(IssCnt)

                'MsgBox DPno & vbCrLf & TmpStr & vbCrLf & MajArr(IssCnt) & vbCrLf & MinArr(IssCnt) & vbCrLf & DoArr(IssCnt) & vbCrLf & FullArr(IssCnt)
                IssCnt = IssCnt + 1
            ElseIf FoundIt = True Then
                'assuming folders are scanned in order? if a non-matching one is subsequently found then stop looking
                FoundIt = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'temporarily stick screenupdating on to give user some feedback on progress!
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'IOMaxValOfIntArray is a function that gets the index of the highest integer in array.
        'This coincides with the index used across other isses, so when "topissue" is concatenated it will match the highest issue found.
        IssCnt = IOMaxValOfIntArray(FullArr)
        TopIssue = "_" & MajArr(IssCnt) & "_" & MinArr(IssCnt) & "_" & DoArr(IssCnt)
        'if one was never found then the array will be empty.
        If TopIssue = "___" Then
            TopIssue = "Not found"
            Cells(DpScroll, StartCol + 4) = "Not Found"
            'this prints the DPno to an error message displayed at the end.
            IssErr = True
            IssErrMsg = IssErrMsg & vbCrLf & DpNo
        End If
        '''Print the full issue number, and time found.
        Cells(DpScroll, StartCol + 4) = Format(Timer() / 86400, "HH:MM:SS")
        'MsgBox TopIssue
        Cells(DpScroll, StartCol + 2) = TopIssue
        ' save in case of a rage quit. in this way those that have been retrieved are not reset.
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'reset array
        For I = 0 To IssCnt
            MajArr(I) = ""
            MinArr(I) = ""
            DoArr(I) = ""
            FullArr(I) = ""
        Next
    Next

    If IssErr Then MsgBox IssErrMsg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to put more detail later... But you can use the Dir command to return file system objects that match a pattern...
So first you would run Dir("DP0123456*") to get your first match. Then just Dir() to get subsequent ones until it returns with a blank (meaning no more matches)

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Shell32` usage. Place this code at the beginning of your `Sub`:

```
' add reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation (Shell32)
Const SHCONTF_FOLDERS = &H20
Const SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN = &H80
Dim Shell As Shell32.Shell
Dim FolderItems As Shell32.FolderItems
Dim FolderItem As Shell32.FolderItem
Set Shell = New Shell32.Shell
```

And here is a part of code to populate the arrays:

```
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set FolderItems = Shell.NameSpace(StrSourceFolder).Items
    FolderItems.Filter SHCONTF_FOLDERS + SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, DpNo & "_*"
    IssCnt = 0
    For Each FolderItem In FolderItems
        TmpStr = Replace(FolderItem.Name, DpNo & "_", "")
        MajArr(IssCnt) = Left(TmpStr, 2)
        MinArr(IssCnt) = Mid(TmpStr, 4, 2)
        DoArr(IssCnt) = Right(TmpStr, 3)
        'combine these for later
        FullArr(IssCnt) = MajArr(IssCnt) & MinArr(IssCnt) & DoArr(IssCnt)
        'MsgBox DPno & vbCrLf & TmpStr & vbCrLf & MajArr(IssCnt) & vbCrLf & MinArr(IssCnt) & vbCrLf & DoArr(IssCnt) & vbCrLf & FullArr(IssCnt)
        IssCnt = IssCnt + 1
    Next
```